# Run Quicksort and Mergesort in parallel to measure time - JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, quicksort, mergesort

I saw these two JS code blocks for [Quick sort](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1582075) and [Merge sort](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1243323)
and I would like to practise some parallel execution to measure the time each code needs to sort the bars. I know JS works in single thread and single process but I also think there is a good way how to measure the time.

How can I do that? Is it with some special library or some trick in JavaScript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I know JS works in single thread and single process...

Nope. Not even on browsers. The *language* has nothing to say about threading. It's a matter of environment. For instance, on browsers, there's one main UI thread and as many [web worker](http://www.w3.org/TR/workers/) threads as you want to create.

But I wouldn't use multi-threading to compare the time two different sorting algorithms take. Instead, just test them separately, ensuring nothing else is going on in the background. Tool recommendations are off-topic for SO, but you don't need any particular tool here. Do repeated tests, with warmups, and average the results. Try to come up with ways that you could make the data suit one kind of sort or the other, and test both ways on that data as well as random data. Ensure that measuring the times isn't interfering with the sorting itself. Ensure that the sorted results are correct (otherwise it doesn't matter how fast it runs). Etc.